# Google Maps API, Adding My Own Location

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

I'm just starting to mess around with Google Maps API and would like to set the default location to mine using geolocation.

I'm able to successfully store the latitude and longitude into variables, however how do I apply them into the following code:

```
function init() {

    var mapOptions = {
      //NEED TO ADD MY VARIABLES HERE, BUT WHAT'S THE CORRECT SYNTAX?
      center: { lat: 34.052234, lng: -118.24368499999999},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
}
```

My variables are **lat_a** and **lng_a**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to provide the geolocation callback code.  1. make the map global. 2. in the geolocation callback set the center of the map to the value returned (assumes the map initialization code runs before the callback of the geolocation service).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: parseFloat(lat_a), lng: parseFloat(lng_a)},
    zoom: 8
 };
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that too, but in the console it says those items aren't numbers.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. I needed to wrap the whole thing inside of: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {}

Comment: Originally I had navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {...} get the coordinates outside of init() but after placing it inside, it worked.